# How to remove the id from the url and submit the title in url using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, .htaccess

i am working on the job posting page in our website and we need to submit the each and every job title to be indexed with google instead of id's which are shown in url.
I need to see the each and every job title in URL instead of id's.
can any one help me how to do this.

you can check my site url from below link

http://www.anantha.co.in/viewJob.php?id=689

Kind Regards
Suresh

Comment: Then, Pass 'Job Title' Instead.

Comment: This is a much bigger issue than just hacking around the URL string. For better SEO you should to implement a URL routing scheme which allows you to add keywords relevant to the content in to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to work on HTACCESS to have this done. For example if you want your URL like example.com/title.html , it can be achieve by .htaccess by mod rewrite. You can get title as parameter as you can by GET.

A good example:
https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/